# How to generate txt file then force download in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to set a handler to `<asp:Button>` element. When user clicks, txt file must be generated in code-behind and must be automatically downloaded by user. There is no need to get any data from user. All file content will be generated in code behind. For example, how to return to user a txt file with content of this variable:

```
string s = "Some text.\nSecond line.";
```

Answer (score 7):

For this kind of job you should create file on the fly.
Please see the code:

```
    protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "Some text.\r\nSecond line.";

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=testfile.txt");
        Response.AddHeader("content-type", "text/plain");

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Just note for new line you need to use \r\n instead of only \n or use WriteLine function for each line

Comment: I like idea, but it doesn't work for some reason. I can see in debugger that response was created but there is no file downloaded in result. Btw, here is a button markup. Maybe problem here: `<asp:Button ID="GenerateFullEmailList" runat="server" CssClass="btn green" Text="Email list" OnClick="GenerateFullEmailList_Click" />`

Comment: It is a very common way and must be correct. I think it could be some kind of browser setting causes this issue. can you try with another browser

Comment: Or It might be block by your anti virus

Comment: I disabled anti-virus and changed the browser. Result the same. Could it be connected with postbacks or something like this?

Comment: Could you please replace second addheader function with    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

Comment: result still the same

Comment: Did you put the last line: Request.End().

Answer (score 1):

You can simply generate the file on the server side and then push it down to the user. `s` would be the content of the File that you will generate.

#### Creating the File

Creating a new File is as simple as writing the data to it,

```
// var s that you're having
File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/NewFile.txt")).Close();
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/NewFile.txt"), s);
```

This will create a new file (if doesn't exist) and write the content of the variable s to it.

#### Pushing it down to the user

You can allow the user to download it, using the following code,

```
// Get the file path
var file = Server.MapPath("~/NewFile.txt");
// Append headers
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=NewFile.txt");
// Open/Save dialog
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
// Push it!
Response.TransmitFile(file);
```

This will let him have the file you just created.

Comment: Using disk is not a smart way to do this, it can be done in memory as disk IO introduces both latency and concerns about multi-threading (which are very likely problems in an ASP.net application).

Answer (score 0):

I do have a similar case but a little bit more complex usecase.

I do generate different types of files. I wrote a container class Attachment witch holds the content type and the value of the generated file as an Base64 string.

```
public class Attachment {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string ContentType {get;set;}
   public string Base64 {get;set;}
}
```

This enables me to serve different file types with the same download method.

```
protected void DownloadDocumentButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ASPxButton button = (ASPxButton) sender;
  int attachmentId = Convert.ToInt32(button.CommandArgument);

  var attachment = mAttachmentService.GenerateAttachment(attachmentId);

  Response.Clear();
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename={attachment.Name}");
  Response.AddHeader("content-type", attachment.ContentType);
  Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.Base64));
  Response.End();
}
```